# while going over perlmonks tutorial on something

Tags: perl

I thought I understood everything but I guess I don't understand the difference beteween $max->() and $temp_score = $max->().. Why does one print out pointer address and latter prints out actual value?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub get_max {
    my $max = $_[0];

    return sub {
        for (@_) {
            $max = $_ if ! defined $max || $_ > $max;   
        }
    print "inside of get_max is max currently is $max\n";
        return $max;
    };
}


my $max = get_max();
while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    $max->($_);
       my $temp_score = $max->();
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>inside while loop, max is $max->()\n";
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>inside while loop, max2 is $temp_score\n";
}

my $high_score = $max->();

print "high_score is $high_score\n";
__END__
90
91
92
87
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why does one print out pointer address...

I'm assuming that you refer to the output of this line:

```
    print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>inside while loop, max is $max->()\n";
```

In this case it prints `$max` not `$max->()` since it expands inside the string only the variable but does not call the function. Thus it results in the value of `$max` which is a function pointer followed by the string `->()`:

```
 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>inside while loop, max is CODE(0x242cf30)->()
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to test this out.  Will get back to u as soon as i go near internet with laptop